# Java Exception Manager - Enterprise Level

Tags: logging, jira, error-logging, log4jdbc, syslog4j

I am looking for an industrial strength FOSS logger for an Enterprise Java application, before I embark on re-inventing the wheel...

We have all seen large apps that log exceptions (think SAPesque), but beyond log4J type stuff. These features are some of what I am looking for:

- Provide end-users with a reference number they can track or report on
- log exceptions centrally (no, not like syslog, rather into a database)
- create logs in a ticketing help-desk (Jira et al)
- automatic statistics (these sections / name spaces are troublesome)
- automatic characterization (these exceptions are like those exceptions)
- automatic guidance - This exception has occurred 10x, it is being tracked on this Jira and will be fixed on this release...
- Operator console or API (REST is good..) see details users cannot see
- Developer console or API - see even more details (like data hidden from operators)

And anything else you can think of :)